# Azure WebJob keeps on running even after the task is completed

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have created a webjob which internally calls azure batch processing so webjob remains idle for about 20 minutes.
As the idle timeout for webjob is only 4-5 min and my webjob is getting failed because of this, So I have changed the time through property "WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT" to 20 minutes.

After making this change I'm facing new issue, now webjob remains in running status even after the batch work is completed and status is not setting to completed

Would be great if anyone can help me on this

Comment: As I known, we could configure `WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT` in seconds to increase idle timeout for a triggered WebJob. According to the new issue you encountered, would you please provide some code of your WebJob?

Comment: I was able to resolve this, there was some issue in the code, Thanks for your reply on thread @Bruce-MSFT

Comment: solution for this please

Comment: Please can you share what the fix was @MMT.?

Comment: There was a infinite loop in code which caused this error in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you did not add code Console.Readline() on your web job